# Unity.Mvc3: how to resolve a constuctor with a concrete param and several interface params

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using Unity.Mvc3 and have the following constructor:

```
public ProductCalculator(
        string connectionString, 
        IOrderDataAccess orderDataAccess,
        IProductDataAccess productDataAccess)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        _orderDataAccess = orderDataAccess;
        _productDataAccess = productDataAccess;
    }
```

How to resolve this? I've tried that:

```
private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IProductCalculator, ProductCalculator>(
            new InjectionConstructor(ConnectionString));

        return container;
    }
```

and get the following error:

**The type ProductCalculator does not have a constructor that takes the parameters (String).**

Comment: How is it possible that the `ProductCalculator` needs a connection string? You are missing an abstraction. You probably need something like an `IConnectionFactory` that is in control of managing connections.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, so give a try -

```
container.RegisterType<IOrderDataAccess, OrderDataAccess>();
container.RegisterType<IProductDataAccess, ProductDataAccess>();
string ConnectionStringVariable = "Your Connection string";
container.RegisterType<Iproduct, product>(
                    new InjectionConstructor(ConnectionStringVariable,
                    container.Resolve<IOrderDataAccess>(),
                    container.Resolve<IProductDataAccess>()));
```